# SandForce controller SSD Garbage Collection for systems without TRIM support

Tags: macos, osx-snow-leopard, performance, ssd

Mac OS X does not seem to support TRIM, the command that tells SSD drives they can reuse a block. This means, after a while of usage, writing over much of the SSD, [performance degrades](https://superuser.com/questions/154248/fix-degraded-ssd-performance-on-mac-without-full-erase).

Since waiting for Apple to support TRIM s probably futile, I'm looking for alternatives. [This article](http://macperformanceguide.com/SSD-RealWorld-SevereDuty.html) (also see other pages) suggests that the OWC Mercury Extreme, an SSD with the [SandForce SF1200 controller](http://eshop.macsales.com/item/Other%20World%20Computing/SSDMXE200/) has [well-performing garbage collection](https://superuser.com/questions/177997/ssd-garbage-collection-os-x) so not having TRIM does not mean I need to throw away my SSD after some use. Right?

Now on to the questions -- is anything questionable about the review, methods, conclusions etc.?
Do the results translate to other SSDs that use the same SF-1200 chip, such as the OCZ Agility 2 Extended or Vertex 2 Extended (that are actually available in Europe)?

Comment: [Anandtech](http://www.anandtech.com/show/3681/oczs-vertex-2-special-sauce-sf1200-reviewed/) reviewed the OCZ Vertex 2 and explicitly mentioned performanced after writing without TRIMming, and while not as good as the review for the OWC SSD is still quite impressive. The site also describes the [differences between Agility 2 and Vertex 2](http://www.anandtech.com/show/3661/understanding-sandforces-sf1200-sf1500-not-all-drives-are-equal). I'm confident the Vertex 2 is a good drive and consider this question answered. However, if someone knowledgable wants to add worthwhile info, I'll accept.

Comment: If there are no responses in  future, you may want to consider posting that comment as an answer and selecting it. This way question won't be automatically bumped every few weeks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Doing what AndrejaKo suggested above, since this question is essentially answered.

> [Anandtech](http://www.anandtech.com/show/3681/oczs-vertex-2-special-sauce-sf1200-reviewed/) reviewed the OCZ Vertex 2 and explicitly mentioned performance after writing without TRIMming, and while not as good as the review for the OWC SSD it's still quite impressive. The site also describes the [differences between Agility 2 and Vertex 2](http://www.anandtech.com/show/3661/understanding-sandforces-sf1200-sf1500-not-all-drives-are-equal).  I'm confident the Vertex 2 is a good drive and consider this question answered.